# An elementary problem in Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

> Two dice, red and white, are rolled $20\:000$ times. What is the conditional probability that the red is $3$ given that the white is $6$?

I know the formula for this is:
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

My question is simple. For $P(B)$, the probability that a $6$ is rolled, should I use $3\:932/20\:000$, the number of times a chart shows a $6$ being rolled divided by the total number of trials *OR* should I use $1/6$ because a die has a $1/6$ chance rolling a $6$?

Comment: We have to find the conditional probability of the red dice getting a three given that the white dice is a six. So, which observation is to be noted out of the $20,000$ rolls?

Comment: Because 19,999 isn't enough.

Comment: According to Principles of Statistics this experiment was performed by the Swiss astronomer Wolf in 1850. The white die was slightly biased. I suppose that information could be useful to a gambler.

Answer (score 1):

it is 1/6 since these two dice are independent no matter what you get on white the probability of getting 3 on red is 1/6

to be more precise P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B)

which makes P(A|B)= P(A)* P(B) / P(B) = P(A) =1/6

unless there are any underlying conditions you haven't mentioned and assuming these are fair dice the answer is correct

Comment: I think the question asks to estimate the conditional probability based on the results of the 20,000 rolls.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is referring to a famous experiment that is recounted in many books on probability and statistics, probably starting with John Maynard Keynes's *Treatise on probability*.  A nice description, with the complete table, can be found [here](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/entropy.concentration.pdf).  One sees that the white die came up six a total of $3932$ times, and among those rolls, the red die came up three $629$ times, for a conditional probability of $629/3932 \approx 0.1599694$.

It's worth noting that the red die came up three $3176$ times out of the $20,000$ rolls, for an unconditional probability of $3176/20,000 = 0.1588$.

The short answer to the OP's question is that $629/3932$ is the proper answer here, not $1/6$, because this problem is (or seems to be) about an actual experiment, not an idealized one.  As Keynes put it, "This, then is the sole conclusion of these immensely laborious experiments -- that Wolf’s dice were very ill made."